# Remember Me Checkbox in Login Form

Tags: vue.js

I have a Login form with 2 fields in my Login Component. I also have a remember me checkbox. How can I make it functional when the checkbox is checked. It will remember the email and password.

```
<form>

<div class="form-group-custom">
<label for="name">your email</label>
<div class="form-input-outer">
<input type="email" class="from-input" placeholder="Enter Your Email..." v-model="email" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group-custom">
<label for="name">password</label>
<div class="form-input-outer">
<input type="password" class="from-input" placeholder="Enter Your Password..." v-model="password" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="remember-me">
<input class="styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" value="value1" />
<label for="styled-checkbox-1">remember me</label>
</div>

<div class="login-buttons d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
<button type="submit" class="form-btn">login</button>
</div>
</form>



export default {
  name: "signin",
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save `value1` in the data block, then write a function to handle form submission:

```
data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      value1: false, // remember the user
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      // send form data to the server
    }
  }
```

To connect your button to a method, use `@click="submitForm()` inside the HTML `<button>` tag.

Note a better variable name might be `rememberUser`. Also I notice you're missing `<template>` and `<script>` tags.

Comment: Can you please share me a detailed example.